# What is/are the main purpose(s) of topology?

Tags: general-topology

> The astrophysicists believe if this is true, the universe would be
> finite. The entire cosmos may be only three or four times larger than
> the limits of the observable universe, which is about 45 billion
> light-years away. If true, a doughnut-shaped universe also has the
> possibility of allowing a spaceship that goes in one direction to
> eventually return to where it started without turning around.
>
> The shape of the universe is something that astronomers have been
> debating for decades. Some believe the universe is flat where parallel
> lines stay parallel forever. Others believe the universe is closed,
> being the parallel lines eventually intersect. Astronomers say the
> geometry of the universe dictates its fate. While open universes
> continue to expand forever, a closed universe eventually collapses in
> on itself. Observations focusing on cosmic microwave background, which
> is the flash of light released when the universe is only 380,000 years
> old, have established that our universe is flat and parallel lines
> will stay parallel forever with an ever-evolving universe. However,
> there’s more to shape than geometry, and topology has to be
> considered. **Topology allows shapes to change while maintaining the
> same geometric rules.**
>
> An example is a sheet of flat paper that has parallel lines that stay
> parallel. If you roll the paper into a cylinder, the parallel lines
> are still parallel. If you take that sheet of paper and connect the
> opposite ends while it’s rolled like a cylinder, you get the shape of
> a doughnut, which is still geometrically flat. The team believes the
> warping occurs beyond observational limits and will be very difficult
> to detect. The team was looking at perturbations, which describe bumps
> and wiggles in the cosmic microwave background radiation temperature.
> They believe there could be a maximum size to the perturbations that
> could reveal the universe’s topology. Buchert and his team emphasize
> their results are preliminary and note that instrument effects could
> explain some of their results.

https://www.slashgear.com/astrophysicists-believe-the-universe-may-be-shaped-like-a-giant-3d-doughnut-20683133/

I was reading this article and I was wondering about what might be the main purpose of topology or at least one of the main purposes. Could it be that one of the main purpose is to see how n-1 dimensional plane behave when the plane is projected onto a n dimensional geometric object without breaking the geometrical rules of the n-1 dimensional plane (by giving it a curvature or a n dimensional geometric property to outside observers while the inside observers sees the n-1 dimensional plane as being a n-1 dimensional plane from the inside? Could you explain so that a layman can understand?

Comment: Much of what you seem curious about sounds like curvature and related concepts from *geometry* (especially differential geometry), and not topology.

Comment: Topology roughly tells you how close points are together.

Comment: @KentaS A topology emphatically *doesn't* tell you how close points are together. What a topology *does* tell you is something about the "perturbation-stability" (= openness) of sets of points.

Comment: @NoahSchweber that's why I said "roughly," which to be fair may be slightly misleading. However, I do think topology defining "closeness" is *one* good way to look at topology. For instance, I view discrete topology as having the points miles away from each other, while I view trivial topology as having the points *really* close to each other, so as to be unable to distinguish between them.

Comment: Of course, I do agree with you in that topology doesn't define "closeness" explicitly, in the way metric spaces do.

Answer (score 1):

When talking about a [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space) in mathematics, one refers to a family of sets which satisfies some properties. Using topologies one can define limits and continuous functions. Then, using continuous functions one defines topological equivalence ([homeomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism)) of manifolds (e.g. surfaces). Topologically equivalent manifolds share several properties. This is what is referred to in the bold sentence of your text.